# Flowfield pathfinding behind obstacles on symmetrical grid

Tags: path-finding, grid

I use Fast iterative method to create my flow field. However when an obstacle is on the same axis as the destination, the vectors behind the obstacle point directly to the destination and ignore the obstacle. I think the following image describes the problem best:

Blue is the destination
Red rectangle is an obstacle (black dots mark blocked cells)

On the middle left you can see how the flow field points directly to the destination and ignores the obstacle.

[image]

I think this is due to the 'nature' of the eikonal equation, creating the same distance for upward/downward direction in the middle behind the obstacle. I calculate the vector by:

x = T(x - 1) - T(x + 1)
y = T(y - 1) - T(y + 1)

I currently solve it by post-processing the field and fix cells behind obstacles that point to the destination. However I'd like to know if there is a better method.

Related posts:

[How does Flow Field pathfinding work?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/387/how-does-flow-field-pathfinding-work)

[Fix my Flow Field pathfinding](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153000/fix-my-flow-field-pathfinding)